# Get ECT data in SharePoint JSOM

Tags: javascript, odata, sharepoint-2013

I have configured an external content type in my sharepoint online site which is connected to the oData source. Using JSOM of sharepoint i want to get values from that content type. I also have created external lists for that ECT and can see ECT items in that list. So i think my ect is properly configured. But when i want to get those items using JS code i get an error `Cannot find a MethodInstance with Name 'ReadSpecificVideo' of type 'Finder' or an Entity(External Content Type) with name 'Videos' in namespace 'TelerikTvDataServiceDataServiceModels'`

here is my code

```
var ect = ctx.get_web().getAppBdcCatalog().getEntity("TelerikTvDataServiceDataServiceModels", "Videos");
    ctx.load(ect);

    var lob = ect.getLobSystem();
    ctx.load(lob);

    var lobs = lob.getLobSystemInstances();
    ctx.load(lobs);
    var parentObject = this;
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        var filters = ect.getFilters('ReadSpecificVideo');
        ctx.load(filters);

        var filtered = ect.findFiltered(filters, 'ReadSpecificVideo', lobs.get_item(0));
        ctx.load(filtered);

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var a = true;
... other stuff

        }, function (data, args) { alert(args.get_message()); });

    }, function (data, args) { alert(args.get_message()); });
```

when i reach `ctx.load(filtered);` and then execute an async query i get the error mentioned above... who can help ?